# Ebay API - Error #21916587 - Item Variations

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm getting this error (#21916587) and I can't seem to find the missing name.

Here's the message associated with the error: *Missing name in the variation specifications or the variation specification set*.

This also only seems to happen when I have a "complex" type variation. For instance it works as expected if I have have a product that only has different sizes.

Here's the output of what I'm sending to eBay.

```
Array
(
[Variation] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SKU] => 0147852369
                [StartPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5
                    )

                [Quantity] => 5
                [VariationSpecifics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Color
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Red
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Shirt Size
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Adult Medium
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [SKU] => 0147852368
                [StartPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 4
                    )

                [Quantity] => 9
                [VariationSpecifics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Color
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Red
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Shirt Size
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Adult Small
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [SKU] => 0147852367
                [StartPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 5.5
                    )

                [Quantity] => 9
                [VariationSpecifics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Color
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => White
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Shirt Size
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Adult Medium
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [SKU] => 0147852366
                [StartPrice] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 4.5
                    )

                [Quantity] => 8
                [VariationSpecifics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Color
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => White
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [NameValueList] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [Name] => Shirt Size
                                                [Value] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [0] => Adult Small
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[Pictures] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [VariationSpecificName] => Shirt Size
                [VariationSpecificPictureSet] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [VariationSpecificValue] => Adult Small
                                [PictureURL] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => http://www.somesite.local/images/products/canvas-unisex-jersey-short-sleeve-t-shirt-3001c-canvas-red.jpg
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [VariationSpecificName] => Shirt Size
                [VariationSpecificPictureSet] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [VariationSpecificValue] => Adult Small
                                [PictureURL] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => http://www.somesite.local/images/products/2000G_WHITE_large.jpg
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[VariationSpecificsSet] => Array
    (
        [NameValueList] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => Color
                        [Value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Red
                                [1] => White
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Name] => Shirt Size
                        [Value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Adult Medium
                                [1] => Adult Small
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone who runs into this and you know you're not missing a name in the variation or set.

If you look at the array, specifically the VariationSpecifics key you'll notice it has 2 items in it. It should only have 1. Both the Shirt Size and the Color should be inside a single NameValueList key within the VariationSpecifics key.